# React Hook Form & Material UI: errors are undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using React Hook Form v7 with Material UI v5. I have a simple form component as shown below. I have marked the `TextField` as required, however, the error state and helper text are never shown when the value of the field is empty. The value of `errors.title` is always undefined.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get the React Hook Form validation working, i.e. `errors`?

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import backEndApi from '../api/backEndApi';

const UserForm = function () {

  const { control, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, getValues } = useForm();

  const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    backEndApi.post(getValues());
  };

  return (
    <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center" direction="column" paddingTop="10%">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)}>
        <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center" direction="column" spacing={5}>
          <Grid item>
            <Controller
              name="title"
              control={control}
              rules={{ required: true }}
              render={({ field }) => {
                return (
                  <TextField
                    {...field}
                    id="title"
                    label="Title"
                    required
                    error={errors.title}
                    helperText={errors.title && 'Title is required'}
                  />
                );
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Button id="job-submit" color="primary" type="submit" variant="contained">
              Create Job
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </form>
    </Grid>
  );

};

export default UserForm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `rules` conflicts with `required` of `TextField`.

I confirmed it works. (https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-chebyshev-9twrle?file=/src/userForm.js)

```
<Controller
  name="title"
  control={control}
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field }) => {
    return (
      <TextField
        {...field}
        id="title"
        label="Title"
        error={Boolean(errors.title)}
        helperText={errors.title && "Title is required"}
      />
    );
  }}
/>
```

Also you don't have to wrap with `Controller` for such a simple case.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-chebyshev-9twrle?file=/src/userFormWithoutController.js

Comment: getting issue in your controller textfield sandbox example.